# Using an argument from one Function in a separate function

Tags: python, function

I have a function:

```
def create_discs(noDiscs):
```

which when called creates a specified number of discs, so for example:

```
create_discs(5)
```

will create 5 discs.

I then want to use the integer inputted into the create_discs function in a separate function:

```
def hanoi(disc_int):
```

In other words I would like disc_int to equal 5 (or whatever number is inputted)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where do you call `hanoi` from?

Comment: I would say it depends on how these two functions are related, and what calls them... Either you can store the number of discs in a global variable, or you can declare both functions inside a class, with the number of discs as instance attribute,  and create an instance...

Comment: hanoi is just called at the end of my hanoi script. I'm not sure what to put in the call to equate disc_int to noDiscs

Comment: Show us how you are using `create_discs` so that we can tell you the best way to accomplish this. @Roberto gives two decent options.

Answer (score 3):

If you want two functions to share state like this, they should be defined as methods of a class.

```
class Hanoi(object):

    def __init__(self, num_discs):
        self.num_discs = num_discs

    def create_discs(self):
        # use value of self.num_discs

    def hanoi(self):
        # use value of self.num_discs

h = Hanoi(5)
h.create_discs()
h.hanoi()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing `5` to create_discs, can you do:

```
num = 5

create_discs(num)
hanoi(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a closure:

```
def create_discs(num):
    # create some discs
    def hanoi_closure():
        # now num is available within this function
        # do hanoi stuff
        return
    return hanoi_closure

hanoi = create_discs(5)
hanoi()
```

In this case, `create_discs` defined your `hanoi` function within itself so that `num` was within its scope (automatically, no need to store anything in a `global` or a `class`!) and it returned the inner function so you could call it later.

If `create_discs` was already supposed to return something, then you could just return a `tuple` with what it was returning plus the inner function:

```
def create_discs(num):
    # ...
    return what_it_normally_returns, hanoi_closure

create_discs_result, hanoi = create_discs(5)
hanoi()
```